# I don't understand how to implement this logical condition in Python

Tags: python

Good afternoon.
I have a fairly simple question (I think).

Let's say for example that in my program I have these two variables `var0` and `var1`.

During execution if "I find out" that the variable I am using is `var0` (because I randomly select it) then I have to select the other (`var1`) because I have to send it as a parameter to a function.

In summary, given one variable, how do I use the other?
This in two variables..in `3` variables? Do I need a list?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some code that illustrates the problem? From your description, I'm having difficulty understanding your issue.

Comment: filter the list for the variables that are NOT the one you are using and choose from there: choose_other_var = [a for a in mylistofvars if a != var_you_are_using]

Comment: Don't worry, Cory Kramer has already understood and solved the problem. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could randomly select between the two variables, then unpack them

```
import random
x, y = random.sample(['a', 'b'], 2)
```

Now `x` and `y` will each get randomly `'a'` or `'b'`, so whatever value is stored in `x` you know the other value is in `y`.

Comment: Does it work in exactly the same way in three variables?

Comment: Yes you could do `x,y,z = random.sample([4,5,6], 3)` to randomly store from your list into those variables

Comment: Thanks, in 6 minutes I will confirm the best answer (because you answered me very fast!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `random.choice` to randomly choose a variable, then removing that selection from my list of variables, and inputing the variable that remains into my function, which in this case is just a print statement.

```
import random

var1 = 'var1'
var2 = 'var2'

var_list = [var1,var2]
selection = random.choice(var_list)
print('We have selected variable: ', selection)

var_list.remove(selection)
print('Therefore the variable we will send to the program is: ',var_list[0])

%% Output: We have selected variable:  var2
           Therefore the variable we will send to the program is: var1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean:

```
from random import choice

var = [var1, var2]

v = choice(var)

if v == var1:
    v = var2
else:
    v = var1
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use list to do this or in other hand you can use this code.

```
var1 = 3
var2 = 4
result = locals()['var1']
print(result)
result = locals()['var2']
print(result)
```

you can access var by it's name